# Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic application shows error  when i run `ionic cordova build android`

> BUILD FAILED in 4s (node:5692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error:
>   /home/bharathi/ionic/hourli/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed
>   with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an
>   exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

**projects.properties**

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+
cordova.gradle.include.1=com.synconset.imagepicker/app-ignorelinterrors.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=com.synconset.imagepicker/app-androidtarget.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-badge/app-badge.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.6.2
cordova.system.library.5=com.android.support:support-v4:+
cordova.gradle.include.4=cordova-plugin-local-notification/app-localnotification.gradle
cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
cordova.system.library.8=com.android.support:support-v13:26.+
cordova.system.library.9=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2
cordova.gradle.include.5=phonegap-plugin-push/app-push.gradle
```

**build.gradle**

```
 defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
     }
```

i have added multiDexEnabled in build.gradle,still getting the same error  when i try to build.I tried after

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

but still getting the same error

Comment: The likely cause of your issue is conflicting versions of the android v4 support library being specified. From your `project.properties` that's entries 5, 6 & 7 all specifying different versions which will cause a Gradle version collision.

Comment: @DaveAlden I have added its version to 26.0.0,and now the build was success ,does it make any other issues?

Comment: No, if it builds successfully, you are OK. Time to open a beer :-)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56993319/8995811

Answer (score 6):

It occured for me. Fixed with:

```
cordova clean
```

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days trying to fix it I found a solution, in my case the following plugins caused a crash: cordova-admob-sdk, cordova-plugin-firebase and I changed manually the play-services-ads version in "project.properties" and "build.gradle" files from "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+" to "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0"