# Execution failed for task

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

Getting **Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.** while adding any dependency to my current project.

Checked on SO for the solution but that didn't work in my case.

Please suggest the possible solution for this error.
TIA

Comment: What dependency did you add?

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher I added  `implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'`
    `implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8'`
   `implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.2.0'`

Comment: remove dependency 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2' and check if it compiles? Then try latest version of same.

Comment: @RanjanKumar already done this. Removed this dependency and working fine. Tried with latest version as well as with older version, still same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worked. Finally uninstalled the Android Studio and re-installation worked.

Uninstall/Reinstall worked in my case but you should try other solution first and if nothing helps you, then you should follow this as it is time taking task.

**UPDATE:**

After a long research just resolved this issue by removing the unnecessary dependencies from gradle.

Try it and let me know.